# Is this clean coding? (.Net, C#)

Tags: c#

In one of our projects I found this code

```
class A 
{
     private B b = new B();

     protected void AMethod()
     {
         var x = b.DomeSome();
     }
}
```

My question, is this a "clean" way of coding? Would it be cleaner to instantiate b in AMethod?
Does is depend?

Comment: The example is too abstract to make any comment about the cleanliness of the pattern.

Comment: It's hard to discuss design questions like this when the domain makes no sense. Please post a meaningful example, i.e., no B's no A's no DomeSome's, but classes that represent something.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is a good site for these types of questions.

Comment: It is usually preferable to use "lazy loading" to create instances of new objects on demand. This code will instantiate `B` as soon as the class is created, consuming resources that may never be needed.

Comment: If I found *this code* in one of our projects I would **delete it**.

Comment: .. or at least change the variable names to something meaningful...

Comment: I assume he has changed names to A & B for posting here.. if these are present in actual code.. CHANGE IT NOW !!

Comment: @jamietre: No. It's usually preferable to use whatever is simpler and fits the requirements. *Lazy loading* is not a silver bullet because it may consume resources (i.e. time) when you can't afford to.

Comment: I think its obvious he has changed the class names for this example...

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering. Answers helped me anyway a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an instance of b in `AMethod`, then the variable will lost after `AMethod` ends. So each call of `AMethod` will create a **new** object B.

On the other hand, having the variable declared at class level (like in your example) will allow you to reuse the instance of B for all the calls of `AMethod`.

There is not precise answer on how is cleaner unless your provide us with more context

Answer (score 2):

If `DomeSome` changes the state of `B` the logic would be different if `B` was instantiated on every call of `AMethod`.

With this amount of code given: The code is clean and it depends.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be cleaner to instance b in AMethod?

It would be different. In the current code b is instantiated when A is instantiated.

> Does ist depend?

Yes

Answer (score 0):

Yes It totally **depends** upon you requirement.. That `b` variable of type `B` may be needed somewhere else too so it has been declared in the `Class`.

And there is no hard defined specifications on `clean coding`. Keep coding as long as its concise, understandable and does what it needs to do.

Also I assume you have changed variable names to A & B for posting here.. if these are present in actual code.. CHANGE IT NOW !!